# Variables Not Being Retained

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

Alrighty.

My problem is with the Javascript Objects `itemList` and `priceList` - they are not retained properly into the `.then()` section.

Here's the part that I'm having trouble with:

```
var stmt = `SELECT * FROM SRV${msg.guild.id}`;
var itemList = {};
var priceList = {};
var num = -1;
sql.each(stmt, function(err, row) {
    num++
    if(row.items!="ITEMS") { itemList[num] = row.items; }
    if(row.prices!="PRICES") { priceList[num] = row.prices; }
    console.log("---------\n" + JSON.stringify(itemList, null, 4) + "\n" + JSON.stringify(priceList, null, 4));
})
.then((itemList, priceList) => {
    console.log("----E----\n" + JSON.stringify(itemList, null, 4) + "\n" + JSON.stringify(priceList, null, 4) + "\n----E----");
    let cmd = require("./itemsPROCESS.js");
    cmd.run(transfer, msg, args, itemList, priceList);
});
```

And here's the important bit that it outputs:

[image: Outputs]

I've tried using strings instead of Javascript Objects, but it doesn't seem to like that either, and it outputs the same.

The `5` and `undefined` part should resemble the bit above it, but it doesn't.

Might it have something to do with the `null` parts? If so, will that mean it won't work with `true` - `false` - `undefined` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the arguments `itemList` and `priceList` and your code should just be fine.

The `itemList` you are referring inside the `.then` function is actually what is resolved by the SQL promise.

```
.then(() => {...});
```

Comment: Ouch. I'm pretty new to ES6 stuff, as I don't usually work in Node.JS. Can you also tell me why it's outputting what it is? Am I accidentally assigning random values to `itemList` and `priceList` when I use it in the function?

Comment: Sure.... the `.then` function generally gets the resolved value from the Promise as its first argument. I have never seen a second argument there. It is useful in cases where you want some value(s) to be passed from your `async` function to the function inside `.then`.

In your case, the sql.each returns a promise which on resolution, returns a value of 5.. something like promise.resolve(5). This comes in as an argument to then .then function and you get to print the value 5

Comment: Thanks! Accepted your answer.

Comment: @PlutonusCommissions glad I could be of your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `itemList` and `priceList` of global scope so don't redefine them in local scope of `then`. Just remove those arguments from `then`

```
.then(() => {
    console.log("----E----\n" + JSON.stringify(itemList, null, 4) + "\n" + JSON.stringify(priceList, null, 4) + "\n----E----");
    let cmd = require("./itemsPROCESS.js");
    cmd.run(transfer, msg, args, itemList, priceList);
});
```